# I got my app Crash when i swipe in viewpager and tab in tablayout

Tags: java, android

**activity_viber.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:menu="@menu/home_menu">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**viber.java**

```
public class Viber extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PagesAdapter pageadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viber);

        TabLayout tab = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("Contact").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_contact_phone_black_24dp));
        tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("Add").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_person_add_black_24dp));
        tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("Message").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_message_black_24dp));

        pageadapter = new PagesAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageadapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab));
        tab.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.search:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //startActivity(new Intent(this,Search.class));
                break;
            case R.id.publicacc:
                //startActivity(new Intent(Viber.this,Search.class));
                Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**PagesAdapter.java**

```
public class PagesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int nooffrags=3;
    public PagesAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                ContactFragment cf = new ContactFragment();
                return cf;
            case 1:
                return new AddContactFragment();
            case 3:
                return new MessageFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return nooffrags;
    }
}
```

I had added 3 tab and when i swipe the view pager it will load for a sec and crash and same in tab.When tabbed load for a sec and crash. And also it the optionitemselected when i check for the item being clicked or not it clicked but when i click with `startActivity(new Intent(this,Search.this));` it again crash the system or app any solution.

Comment: where is your crash reports

Comment: Can you post the crash trace here

Answer (score 1):

inside your PagesAdapter.java inside your getItem(int Position) add case 2: because when you swap to 3 it gets the position value 2 and Case 2 is not available so it will return default value i.e. null and you will get nullPointerException

Comment: in my menu item click if i use startActivity(new Intent(this,Search.class)) i got my app crash

Comment: for this please share your log cat

Comment: when you are inside interface listener please use  ClassName.this instead of only this

Comment: please declare your search activity inside your AndroidManifest.xml 
like
<activity android:name=".Search"/>

Answer (score 0):

in `PagesAdapter.java`: `case 3:` should be `case 2:`

Answer (score 0):

use this because Case 2 is not available so it will return default value

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                ContactFragment cf = new ContactFragment();
                return cf;
            case 1:
                return new AddContactFragment();
            case 2:
                return new MessageFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }


    }
```

instead of this

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                ContactFragment cf = new ContactFragment();
                return cf;
            case 1:
                return new AddContactFragment();
            case 3:
                return new MessageFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }


    }
```